# Mule DataWeave Group by And Sum

Tags: sum, mule, dataweave

I am doing something rather simple and hope that I am just missing a simple statement, I am trying to do a group by and sum but can not seem to be able to make DataWeave complete the task for me.  Any help would be much appreciated!

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getRecordsResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<getRecordsResult>
       <company>0a6979a72ba5020092d4a5a667da15ac</company>
       <u_billed_amount>504</u_billed_amount>
</getRecordsResult>
<getRecordsResult>
       <company>548839a72ba5020092d4a5a667da15e0</company>
       <u_billed_amount>29.17</u_billed_amount>
</getRecordsResult>
<getRecordsResult>
       <company>0a6979a72ba5020092d4a5a667da15ac</company>
       <u_billed_amount>33.75</u_billed_amount>
</getRecordsResult>
```

And the Following in a dataWeave expression -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://www.service-now.com/u_incident_task

---
results: {(
    payload.getRecordsResponse.*getRecordsResult groupBy $.company map        {

    amtToBill: ($.u_billed_amount)  

   } 
)}
```

Which yields the desired grouping, however I need to Sum the amount billed.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results>
  <amtToBill>
      <u_billed_amount>29.17</u_billed_amount>
  </amtToBill>
  <amtToBill>
      <u_billed_amount>504</u_billed_amount>
      <u_billed_amount>33.75</u_billed_amount>
  </amtToBill>
</results>
```

What I need is the following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results>
  <amtToBill>
      <u_billed_amount>29.17</u_billed_amount>
  </amtToBill>
  <amtToBill>
      <u_billed_amount>537.75</u_billed_amount>
  </amtToBill>
</results>
```

I know there has to be a summation in dataWeave, I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer, just do this -

```
amtToBill: sum $.u_billed_amount
```

Comment: While I found my Answer, when I add the company the results go haywire